# Order of the group associated to a quotient of a lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups, integer-lattices

Let $A=[A_{ij}]$ be a $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite integer-valued matrix. Define elements of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ $v_i=[A_{i1},A_{i2},...,A_{in}]$ where I am treating them as row vectors. Quotient $\mathbb{Z}^n$ by imposing $v_i\equiv 0$. We obtain a quotient group which is a finite group $G$ because there are $n$ linearly independent relations $v_i\equiv 0$. Why is the order of $G$ equal to the determinant of $A$?

Comment: Are you using a summation convention? That is not too common here, so you should at least mention it or clarify

Comment: Question: with what operation is a lattice an Abelian group? I don't think about this very often...

Comment: A lattice is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as a group. The operation is addition.

Comment: that tells me almost nothing. Can't the operation be given in terms of meet and join? Oh, it looks like you've edited the definition of the lattice since then. I think I see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that the order of $G$ transforms in the expected way when we perform elementary row and column operations, and reduce to the case where $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using rational numbers while performing elementary row operations here. If you use integers, then you can reduce it to upper diagonal form and then it is clear why the order is the determinant. Thanks.